# PHP script for twitter returning too much data

Tags: php, json, parsing, twitter

So, this is my current php script I am running.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("twitteroauth.php"); 
$consumerkey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$consumersecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$accesstoken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$accesstokensecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
 $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
 return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$hashtag_list = array(
    "breakingbad" => "breakingbad",
    "espn" => "espn",
    "gameofthrones" => "gameofthrones",
);
$notweets = 1;

foreach ($hashtag_list as &$hashtag) {
    $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=".$hashtag."&result_type=popular&count=".$notweets);

    echo json_encode($tweets);
}
?>
```

The problem is, is that when I run this script in terminal I am getting back an insane amount of information. On top of that, I am not getting back the one tweet per show I was requesting and instead I am getting about 12 tweets per hashtag. Can anyone tell me why I am getting so much data. Also why Twitter made 1.1 and decided to digitally punch developers in the face.

If you are curious about what I am getting back here is a very small amount of the type of data that is returning:

```
 "statuses":[{"metadata":{"result_type":"popular","iso_language_code":"en"},"created_at":"Thu Dec 05 21:06:49 +0000
  2013","id":408704034040995840,"id_str":"408704034040995840","text":"Let's take it all the
  way back. See the latest #BreakingBad news: http:\/\/t.co\/dINizWJhqh #tbt 
  http:\/\/t.co\/tfYirPuMNv","source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.socialflow.com\" 
        rel=\"nofollow\">SocialFlow<\/a>","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":25399731,"id_str":"25399731","name":"Breaking Bad","screen_name":"BreakingBad_AMC","location":"Albuquerque, New Mexico ","description":"For more information, go to http:\/\/t.co\/RvmSIdNAJH. #BreakingBad  http:\/\/t.co\/SuRyGtdteo","url":"http:\/\/t.co\/mr1UzInsNt","entities":{"url":{"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/mr1UzInsNt","expanded_url":"http:\/\/www.amc.com","display_url":"amc.com","indices":[0,22]}]},"description":{"urls":
    [{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/RvmSIdNAJH","expanded_url":"http:\/\/amc.com","display_url":"amc.com","indices":[28,50]},

 {"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/SuRyGtdteo","expanded_url":"http:\/\/breakingbadamc.tumblr.com\/","display_url":"breakingbadamc.tumblr.com","indices":
    [66,88]}]}},"protected":false,"followers_count":769339,"friends_count":2051,"listed_count":3379,"created_at":"Thu Mar 19 22:32:21 +0000 
    2009","favourites_count":1462,"utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Quito","geo_enabled":true,"verified":true,"statuses_count":3594,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":
    false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.
    com\/profile_background_images\/378800000085590192\/f6daf83a1f1a3061158eea710e43c246.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000085590192\/f6daf83a1f1a3061158eea710e43c246.png","profile_background_tile":false,
    "profile_image_url
    ":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3764660477\/e0df076073170905b32e62bdb75dc04d_normal.jpeg","profile_image_url_https"
```

Now that is about 5% of the data returning. Now, this isn't a huge problem because I could just parse the JSON, but what I don't understand is why I can't get the single tweet I wanted back. Why so many? All I need is that actual text.

Comment: I may be mistaking but this json looks like a single tweet to me, what you can do is try every single request at https://dev.twitter.com/console and check how your json is formatted.

Comment: This is just a small section of the information that I put up, the actual output is too large to place here. It goes on for a long time after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to double quote the string query parameters, the `q` parameter and the `result_type` parameter.

I tried on https://dev.twitter.com/console and without quotes the number of tweets returned is 15, that is the default number of tweets returned by a call, meaning that the count parameter is not considered,the query I tried is: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q="espn"&count=1&result_type="popular"`.

In your case it should be like this:

`$tweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q="'.$hashtag.'"&count='.$notweets.'&result_type="popular"');`

Comment: Hey, I do have `"&count=".$notweets` at the end in my code and that `$notweets` is set to 1, so I do have it set to one in my query. So, each hashtag should be retuning 1. But I do think you are right in the aspect that it is returning 15 and not 12 like I thought.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is propably the use of json_encode() here - you receive JSON data by twitters API and then you re-encode the JSON again, which is propably the cause of the weird formatting.

Apart from that, the API at */search/tweets.json* (note the **s**) is designed to give you a collection of tweets (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). I could not find a method providing the search for a single tweet, though.

greets,
Robin Heller.